# How do I access a function in an object of functions?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Currently, I have added this code from github into my code:

```
var ExcelFormulas = {

    PVIF: function(rate, nper) {
        return Math.pow(1 + rate, nper);
    },

    FVIFA: function(rate, nper) {
        return rate == 0? nper: (this.PVIF(rate, nper) - 1) / rate;
    },  

    PMT: function(rate, nper, pv, fv, type) {
        if (!fv) fv = 0;
        if (!type) type = 0;

        if (rate == 0) return -(pv + fv)/nper;
        
        var pvif = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper);
        var pmt = rate / (pvif - 1) * -(pv * pvif + fv);

        if (type == 1) {
            pmt /= (1 + rate);
        };

        return pmt;
    },

    IPMT: function(pv, pmt, rate, per) {
        var tmp = Math.pow(1 + rate, per);
        return 0 - (pv * tmp * rate + pmt * (tmp - 1));
    },

    PPMT: function(rate, per, nper, pv, fv, type) {
        if (per < 1 || (per >= nper + 1)) return null;
        var pmt = this.PMT(rate, nper, pv, fv, type);
        var ipmt = this.IPMT(pv, pmt, rate, per - 1);
        return pmt - ipmt;
    },
    
    DaysBetween: function(date1, date2) {
        var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
        return Math.round(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())/oneDay));
    },
    
    // Change Date and Flow to date and value fields you use
    XNPV: function(rate, values) {
        var xnpv = 0.0;
        var firstDate = new Date(values[0].Date);
        for (var key in values) {
            var tmp = values[key];
            var value = tmp.Flow;
            var date = new Date(tmp.Date);
            xnpv += value / Math.pow(1 + rate, this.DaysBetween(firstDate, date)/365);
        };
        return xnpv;
    },

    XIRR: function(values, guess) {
        if (!guess) guess = 0.1;
        
        var x1 = 0.0;
        var x2 = guess;
        var f1 = this.XNPV(x1, values);
        var f2 = this.XNPV(x2, values);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if ((f1 * f2) < 0.0) break;
            if (Math.abs(f1) < Math.abs(f2)) {
                f1 = this.XNPV(x1 += 1.6 * (x1 - x2), values);
            }
            else {
                f2 = this.XNPV(x2 += 1.6 * (x2 - x1), values);
            }
        };
        
        if ((f1 * f2) > 0.0) return null;
        
        var f = this.XNPV(x1, values);
        if (f < 0.0) {
            var rtb = x1;
            var dx = x2 - x1;
        }
        else {
            var rtb = x2;
            var dx = x1 - x2;
        };
        
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            dx *= 0.5;
            var x_mid = rtb + dx;
            var f_mid = this.XNPV(x_mid, values);
            if (f_mid <= 0.0) rtb = x_mid;
            if ((Math.abs(f_mid) < 1.0e-6) || (Math.abs(dx) < 1.0e-6)) return x_mid;
        };
        
        return null;
    }

};
```

I am trying to use the PPMT function in this array. Here is an example I found on how to access the XIRR function:

```
var values =
[
{Date:'1/24/2012',Flow: -10000},
{Date:'6/27/2015',Flow: 12000}
];
alert(ExcelFormulas.XIRR(values));
```

but when I try to do something similar with PPMT, I get null. This is what I am trying:

```
var values =
[
{rate:0.53, per: 1, nper : 12, pv:10000}
];
alert(ExcelFormulas.XIRR(values));
```

Can anyone help me acess the PPMT function? Thank you in advance!

(Side note: You can enter any values as long as it works, I just need an example)

Comment: Do you know how to call a function?

Comment: The function is being called correctly, so this must be about the logic in that function

Comment: Firstly, you are still calling `XIRR` and not `PPMT`.  
Secondly, `PPMT` seems to be asking for 6(!) values, not object, not array -  
In your `values` you have only 4 (missing `type`) -  
You should call it like this: `alert(ExcelFormulas.PPMT(rate, per, nper, pv, fv, type));` - either giving those values: `var rate=0.53, per=1, nper=12, pv=10000, fv=**whatever you need**, type=**whatever you need**;` or directly: `alert(ExcelFormulas.PPMT(0.53, 1, 12, 10000, **whatever fv you need**, **whatever type you need**));`

Comment: You are not calling the `PPMT` function, you are calling the `XIRR` function. In the alert you should have `ExcelFormulas. PPMT(0.53, 1, 12, 10000, , )`. You should have two more values at the end (for **fv** and **type**).

Comment: Thank you everyone! The combination of these answers helped me figure it out and it was really helpful. Sorry for the long response time, I had trouble with my computer

Answer (score -1):

Your `PPMT` function has a control structure at the top of the definition.

```
    PPMT: function(rate, per, nper, pv, fv, type) {
        // will return null if condition is met
        if (per < 1 || (per >= nper + 1)) return null;
        var pmt = this.PMT(rate, nper, pv, fv, type);
        var ipmt = this.IPMT(pv, pmt, rate, per - 1);
        return pmt - ipmt;
    },
```